# How to show output "dymanic" command in jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How to show output "dymanic" command in jupyter? For example bash command "watch".
I can print:

```
%%bash
watch ls
```

And I see nothing
Other example use `!watch ls` but in this case I get clutter in output.
What is the proper way to see output of this kind command?